# Function Relations

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Suppose a function $f : A → B$ is given. Define a relation $∼$ on $A$ as follows:
$a_1 ∼ a_2 ⇔ f(a_1) = f(a_2)$.

a) Prove that $∼$ is an equivalence relation on $A$

b) Since $∼$ is an equivalence relation, it induces a partition of $A$ into equivalence classes. Describe these equivalence classes in the case where $A = R×R$, $B = R$, and $f(x,y) = x+y$.

So, I have tried to prove this, but multiple people say that I need to explain what I am doing completely. How should these be done.

Comment: How do you prove if you don't explain?

Comment: People said I don't explain completely, I just need help with the problem

Comment: What I meant was: show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

For a), in order to prove that the relation ∼ on $A$ defined as :

> $a_1 ∼ a_2 ⇔ f(a_1)=f(a_2)$

is an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) you have to prove that the defining condition for an equivalence relation applies, i.e. that :

> $a ∼ a$ (*Reflexivity*)
>
> if $a ∼ b$, then $b ∼ a$ (*Symmetry*)
>
> if $a ∼ b$ and $b ∼ c$, then $a ∼ c$ (*Transitivity*).

All them are quite simple, using the properties of $=$.

---

For b), in order to prove that, with $A = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R, B = \mathbb R$, and $f(x,y)=x+y$ [I've assumed that $R$ is the set of *real* numbers] we have that :

> $(x_1, y_1) ∼ (x_2, y_2) ⇔ x_1 + y_1 = f(x_1, y_1) = f(x_2, y_2) = x_2 + y_2$.

Thus, the equivalence classes into which $A$ is partitioned by $∼$ are classes of couples of real numbers that "sums" to the same sum.

For example : $(1,2), (-1,4), (1/2, 5/2)$ all belongs to the class $[3]$ because $1+2=-1+4=1/2+5/2=3$.